# How do I implement SSRS Y-Axis like a subquery?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have a report that pulls from a stored procedure. The SP takes a good 3 minutes to run, so I don't want to hit the DB to pull this information more than once. I should already have it in the dataset, so how can I juggle it to get these percents (if at all)?

I have the data in a dataset, and I display a chart based on that data so I can't alter the dataset directly. I need all of the information as it stands. All is well so far. Now, At the bottom of the report, I want a line chart that shows the number of rows that went over a threshold as compared for the ones that did NOT go over that threshold for a given week number. WeekNumber is already a column I collect in my stored proc.

I already have category groups set as WeekNumber, so I believe that my X-Axis should already be set to that. Now, I need to set my Y axis to a percentage of the values that went outside the bounds for that specified week.

My Y-Axis values would then be something like:

```
OveragePercent=FormatPercent(
               (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM ThisWeek WHERE DataSet1.Threshold > 50) /
               (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM ThisWeek WHERE DataSet1.Threshold < 50), 2)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In my SSRS table, I use the DataSet-level sum vs the group-level sum to derive a total percent. The table uses MyDataSet and has a grouping by date. I can tell how many loads were delivered on that day based on Loads.value. I can then determine which weekday had the highest percentage of the weekly loads by using the following.

```
=Sum(Fields!Loads.Value) / Sum(Fields!Loads.Value, "MyDataSet")
```

This gives me overall percentage for each day.

I then needed to filter down some of the data based on whether a flag was set (thus the reason for the main post.) Using the same approach, I discovered the IIF function works at a row level even inside a sum, so it became fairly "obvious" (although it wasn't obvious to me at the time).

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Option1.value=1,Fields!Loads.Value, 0)) / Sum(Fields!Loads.Value, "MyDataSet")
```

This tells me what percent of those same loads for the week had option1 selected.

I hope this solution helps someone else, too.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Shared Dataset instead of an attached one to your report.  Publish the Dataset much the same as you do a DataSource or report.  Once published, click on it in it's appropriate folder.  Choose the drop down arrow and select Manage.  Choose 'Caching' and set a duration.

Usually when I have things that are batch build related versus transactional I cache them.  (Office locations, people, etc.)  This way every morning I get what was input in the last day and then use that data instead of querying every time.  As far as I know this works with procs and functions as well.

Comment: That's great for keeping it around, and I'll look into caching. But how does that help me with how to sub-query? I'm lost as to how to accomplish the task listed above. The above does not work directly, but is written as pseudo code to express what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you are wanting to do an if then grouping, I would create a 'calculated' column but I am confused with your notation as it looks like are getting a single column where there should be multiple as this looks like an expression in SSRS for the chart level not the item level.  Are you setting this expression on line level or in the chart?  I never have used this notation so I was curious as it looks like you are doing an 'either/or' occurence for all returning a single value when generally I see Y axis be the 'amount' and x be the 'date' in a tradiotinal format with both values changing.